# When to use "put it" and when to use "say it"?

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms

From [here](http://esl-bits.net/idioms/id490.htm) I know "put it" means "say it, express it". But have them any distinction of usage? When to use "put it" and when to use "say it"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *put it* can be used in place of to *explain it*; it means to express (a thought or comment) in a particular way, form, or language.

> -Let me **put it** this way: it's only a funny story if you know John. (explain)
>   -When you **put it** like that, I can understand it better. (express)

To say something means you are using words to express a thought; it could be anything, including an explanation. You can use *say it* for *put it*, but not usually the other way around.

> -**Say it** more slowly, please.
>    -What did she **say**?